# How to update activity UI when app is in background/closed

Tags: java, android, service, broadcastreceiver

I have a service which controls my mediaplayer object and when i close my app, a notification is still shown to control playback.

Now when a song is done playing i want update the UI in my activity and i did this with a broadcastreceiver, but this only works when my app is visible and not in the background/closed. (unregistered broadcastreceiver in onPause)

But how do i keep listening for these events when my application is not visible and when the user opens my application again it has the updated UI (new song).

**Service**

```
@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    Log.d(TAG, "OnCompletion called!");

    Intent broadCastReceiverIntentUpdateSong = new Intent(Constants.ACTIONS.BROADCAST_UPDATE_SONG);
    sendBroadcast(broadCastReceiverIntentUpdateSong);

}
```

Comment: If App is close that means there is no UI so no need to update .. For music player stuff i think you should use Bind started  Service..

Comment: `"Now when a song is done playing i want to start another song and [...]"` - use `MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener` then

Comment: @ADM But when i like press previous/next song button in my notification i want to show that song that is playing when i reopen my app, how can i do this?

Comment: With binded Service you can directly set a Callback from Activity to Service which will update the UI part ..

Comment: @pskink that's not my question, when my song is completed playing i want to update my textviews (song, artist) to the next song, but how do i do this when my app is not visible and only my notifcation.

Comment: @ADM my service is bounded, but how to create a callback when my app is opened again with the updated values?

Comment: example: i start a song and then close my app, notifcation shows 3 buttons previous/pause/next, now when i press next song and reopen my app i want to show the values of that song, and not the previous song.

Comment: you want to update text view of not shown app? what for? do that when you reopen your app by calling some binding action that returns the current song info (and playing time for example)

Comment: @pskink yeah thats what i mean, when my app is reopened it shows the current song info

Comment: @pskink i did this with a broadcastreceiver at first, but that doesn't work when my app is not visible.

Comment: You can use event bus to do that

Comment: you have a local service, right? so your service returns some custom `Binder` object, for example `MyMusicActions` - now your client (`Activity`) binds to that service, casts returned `Binder` to `MyMusicActions` and calls `getCurrentSongInfo` - after that you can update your text views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your app starts, it should ask the `Service` for the current state of the player and show that.

While the app is running and in the foreground, it can listen for the broadcast events and update the UI (or its own internal state) accordingly.

When your app goes to the background, it doesn't need to do anything. When it comes again to the foreground (in `onResume()`) it can again ask the `Service`for the current state of the player.

You can have the `Activity` bind to the `Service` and use AIDL to get the current state OR you can just call `startService()` with an `Intent` that contains an ACTION or an EXTRA that indicates that you want to know the current state, and the `Service` can ract to that by sending a broadcast `Intent` containing the current state, which your `Activity` can listen for.